# how to use different color for pch in a legend

Tags: r

I would like to have the pch symbol painted in black in the legend. sample code makes pch same color as lty

```
plot(1:5)
lines(1:5,1:5,col="blue")
legend("topleft","line w. points",lty=1,pch=1,col="blue")
```

there is no col.pch argument, but there must be a lower level routine that can do that.
Thanks

Comment: Technique suggested in the dupe-link answer: `legend("topleft", "", pch=1, lwd=1, lty=0, bty="n")`. The point is to rerun `legend` with an empty (but same-height) title, empty line, and disabled box-lines (`bty`).